# Writing $0$ with $6$ significant figures concisely

Tags: notation

I have some calculations that result in exactly $0$, calculated to 6 significant figures. However, I do not want to write $0.00000$ for each of these calculations, as it makes it look messier. How can I write it more concisely, while still retaining the number of significant figures?

Comment: Perhaps $0\times 10^{-5}$? I admit that would be pretty weird though.

Comment: I mean, if it were *exactly* $0.1$ with $6$ significant figures, would you not write it as $0.10000$ ? What's the difference?

Comment: In my calculations, it is pretty significant if the value is $0.0000$ or $0.0030$, and therefore I do not want to just write $0.0$. But I have a lot of zero-values, which is why I would like to write it more concisely.

Comment: @A-levelStudent If anything, I'd go $0\pm10^{-6}$ or something like that.

Comment: Ok, is the number now exactly zero, or are only there first 6 first digits equal to zero (afaik, significant digits are defined such that there first significant digit must be nonzero)? In case of the former, $a=0$ (instead of $a\approx 0$) should do the job. For the latter, $a=0\pm 10^{-6}$ or $|a|<10^{-6}$ should work. You can also simplify your task and simply say at the beginning: "all numbers were calculated to 5 digits after the point", and then just leave unnecessary zeros away.

Comment: The calculations show that it is zero to 6 significant figures, so it might be $3\times 10^{-7}$ for example. So I guess I should go with the latter then

Comment: While people might understand what you mean, the first significant figure must be non-zero: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures . For example, $0.0010$ has two significant figures, i.e $1.0\cdot 10^{-3}$. As a consequence,  $0.00000$ had zero significant figures. Saying that something is zero to 6 significant figures thus doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all the rest of your numbers will have the decimal point in them, consider writing it as simply $0$ and provide a reference note somewhere that $0$ is $0.00000$ throughout your paper/thesis/work.  You've referred to this as being "exact" in the sense that if it's not exactly zero then it differs only in an $\varepsilon<10^{-6}$ so it's reasonable to use the "exact" value $0$.

This also has the minor advantage that your "exact" $0$s will stand out in tables and lists.

Comment: I think you're right, the easy solution is to simply mention it.